# Conditioning for the four cases of the signs of two numbers

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I have two numbers A and B. I would like to condition for the four cases of the signs of these two numbers. We could do

```
if ((A >= 0) && (B >= 0)){
  // Do something
};
if ((A >= 0) && (B < 0)){
  // Do something
};
if ((A < 0) && (B >= 0)){
  // Do something
};
if ((A < 0) && (B < 0)){
  // Do something
};
```

One could produce a function that outputs different values in each case and then use a `switch{ case:}` statement. For the functions I have thought this doesn't improve the number of comparisons, so there is no much gain.

Which way is recommended for doing this conditioning?

Well, I guess some of those `if`-s could be put inside `else`-s of the others so that not all the conditions have to be evaluated always.

Comment: Note that `if (true) {};` contains two statements. The first statement is `if (true) {}`, and the second statement is `;`. You only want the single statement, so you can remove the trailing semicolons.

Comment: @sharth I didn't understand. Can you explain more or point to where I can read about it? Is it what you are saying that `if (){}if(){};` is allowed and does something different than `if (){};if (){};`?

Comment: In this case I don't think it changes the behavior in any way, it's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (A >= 0)
{
    if (B >= 0)
    {
    }
    else // B < 0
    {
    }
}
else // A < 0
{
    if (B >= 0)
    {
    }
    else // B < 0
    {
    }
}
```